# How can I change the identity, as an IDP, of the WSO2 IS?

Tags: simplesamlphp, wso2-identity-server

How can I change the identity, as an IDP, of the WSO2 IS?
It seems to always call itself localhost!

Some context...

I have deployed an IS and are trying to authenticate against it using SAML2.

Every single example I can find on the internet deploys IS on the same server as the SP, so the IS is on localhost! (by the way, I *do* arrive at a working IS-SP login on a single computer)

But this is not my case, SP and IS are on two different VMs. When I try to authenticate, after logging in, I get an error:
    Caused by: SimpleSAML_Error_Exception: Cannot retrieve metadata for IdP 'localhost' because it isn't a valid IdP for this SP.

I think this error is on the SP side, generated by simpleSamlPhp.

From what I understand, this means that:
* the SP calls the IDP (IS) with a given IDP id (not localhost!) and SP id
* the IDP manages to ask us for login/passwd
* the IDP sends a SAML2 message to the SP
    -> here, the IDP probably calls itself "localhost"
* the SP tries to get config (metadata?) for localhost and can't find any!

So the question is: how can I change the IDP id that the IS uses to answer?

I have changed the server name in carbon.xml, and I have changed every localhost I could find in identities.xml, but to no avail.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 3):

in the management portal of WSO2 IS

1. go to Main / Identity Providers / List
2. Click on "Resident Identity Provider"
3. Expand "Inbound Authentication Configuration"
4. Expand "SAML2 Web SSO Configuration"
5. Fill in the "Identity Provider Entity Id:"

Note that, without knownledge of the keyword "resident", I have not found this information in any doc or web page or blog.
All examples are provided with localhost.
The place this configuration is stored in not intuitive: going to "identity providers" gives a message "No Identity Providers registered", so it's easy to ignore that this is the page where this configuration lies. The link looks like a title. Subtle, but may lose a lot of time! :-)

WSO2 make great products, but tutorials and docs would benefit from being more open or diverse, I don't know. For example one *can* call an endpoint "localhost/saml", but is there any other way to call it? What will change? Is there an example somewhere of a deployment with lots of strange and distinct values for fields, "foo", "bar", etc?

Hope this helps others, via google search at least! :-)